# Same remote repo name for multiple remote repos

Tags: git, github

Say I have 3 projects that I'm working on all of which are on github - "project1", "project2", and "project3".

When creating a git for each individual project will there be any issues in naming each remote the same name?

For example,

`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project1.git`

`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project2.git`

`git remote add origin https://github.com/username/project3.git`

`git push -u origin` shouldn't interfere if I'm working within the specific project directory right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your project you would be having a separate git repository right?
Which would have its own configuration and `.git` folder.

In that case, there is no issue in having remote named as `origin` in all your git repositories.
In fact, when you clone git repository from a remote, the `origin` remote is by default added by git pointing to the remote repository.

Comment: That's correct. I would have separate `.git` folder per /directory/project. I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: In that case there should not be any issue. If you do `git push origin branch_name` in project 1 and project 2, the push would happen to the exact remote repo based on the `.git` config folder.